# How to change elements' appearance with time of the day?

Tags: html, css, darkmode

I want to change the background image of an element and also change content of a heading according to time of the day. If the time is between 6 and 12 it must keep the bg and text according to the morning.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do only with css & html.
You should use js.

If you set your night, day time css you can use this trick :

```
var date = new Date;
var hour = date.getHours();
if(hour > 18 || hour < 6){
    document.body.className += ' nighttime-css';
    // JQUERY => $('body').addClass('nighttime-css')
}else{
    document.body.className += ' daytime-css';
    // JQUERY => $('body').addClass('daytime-css')
}
```

css :

.nighttime-css{background: url('nighttime-bg.jpeg');

.daytime-css{background: url('daytime-bg.jpeg');

Comment: I don't get the meaning of  document.body.className += ' daytime-css';
    // JQUERY => $('body').addClass('daytime-css')

Comment: @HunainAhmed if you add class background will change